# threeparttable not working with subcaption(subtable), error: table inside subtable

Tags: tables, subcaption, threeparttable

I am making a table with two subtables, each subtable has its own tablenotes so I am using threeparttable. But I am prompted with the following error:

```
    ! Package caption Error: table inside subtable.

    See the caption package documentation for explanation.
    Type  H   for immediate help.
    ...                                                                                            
    l.7         \begin{threeparttable}
    If you do not understand this error, please take a closer look
    at the documentation of the `caption' package, especially the
    section about errors.
```

A small example of my code here. It gives the error above. I searched around and it seems `threeparttable` should be able to work with `subcaption`, at least in my simple example here. Could any of you guys ever had issues alike and can point me a way? thanks.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
            \begin{threeparttable}
                \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                    test1 &test1 &test1
                \end{tabular}
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

**Update 1**

Thanks to @cfr's answer, if we put `threeparttable` outside `subtable`, the compile error would be gone. But we have new problems here. Let's first make clear what we want:

1. we want one `table`, which means it has one main caption (`Tab 1`).
2. Inside this top level `table`,  we want two subtables, either these subtables are realized by the tag `subtable` or not doesn't matter.
3. For each subtable, it has its own caption (`Tab a` and `Tab b`) and table notes.

So now we have the following problem:

1. If we put captions for subtable between `threeparttable` and `subtable`(code example as below), the caption for subtable will be using the top level caption counter, we end up with `Tab 1`, `Tab 2` and `Tab 3`.
   [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{top level caption}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \caption{sub level caption 1}
        \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                test1 &test1 &test1\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{threeparttable}

    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \caption{sub level caption 2}
        \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                test2 &test2 &test2\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

2. if we put  `caption` inside the `subtable` environment, the are separated by the `threeparttable` and will give us two `Tab a`. Code example and pic below.
   [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{top level caption}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \caption{sub level caption 1}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                test1 &test1 &test1\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{threeparttable}

    \begin{threeparttable}
        \centering
        \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
        \caption{sub level caption 2}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                test2 &test2 &test2\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compiles fine here. Maybe delete your temporary files and try again?

Comment: Welcome! @MichaelPalmer Are you sure? If so, what distribution etc. do you have?

Comment: @cfr - texlive on debian jessie

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Presumably not current then ... You have the error to look forwards to ;).

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include answers. It is not how this site is supposed to work and it makes the answers pointless. You can always answer your own question if none of the answers are suitable (or there are no answers and you meantime find a solution).

Comment: @cfr, sure updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `caption` package redefines the `threeparttable` environment to set the caption type to `table`. `caption` uses the caption type to check for inappropriate nesting. In this case, it therefore finds an attempt to set caption type to `table` when it is within the `subtable` environment. It knows that isn't allowed, so it gives an error.

The simplest solution, especially if some of your `threeparttable`s are *not* of type `subtable`, is to use the fact that it works if you put the `subtable` inside the `threeparttable`. Alternatively, you can just set the caption type within the `threeparttable` environment rather than using the `subtable` environment at all.

However, as your update points out, this sadly restarts the counter for each sub-table. Here is a solution which avoids this difficulty.

Note that the idea here is that you could change the options for `threepartsubtable` specifically, just as you could change them for `threeparttable`. I think there must be a way to do this more elegantly, but have not yet found one.

That is, I have precious little clue ...

## *Caveat emptor.*

[Edited in light of comments, although not really in accordance with them.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\threepart@subtable{% based on code modified from caption.sty
  \caption@setoptions{threepartsubtable}%
  \caption@ORI@threeparttable
}
\newenvironment{threepartsubtable}{%
  \threepart@subtable
}{%
  \endthreeparttable
}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[threepartsubtable]{subtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Standard main caption}
  \begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      a & b
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Main caption}
  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 1 & test 1 & test 1
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}

  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 2  & test 2 & test 2
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}

  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 3 & test 3 & test 3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}

  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 4  & test 4 & test 4
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Another main caption}
  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 5 & test 5 & test 5
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}

  \begin{threepartsubtable}
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      test 6  & test 6 & test 6
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threepartsubtable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: <code>threepartsubtable</code>]

Comment: Hi @cfr, thanks a lot for the explanation. Moving `threeparttable` out of `subtable` removes the complie error. However, now we have new problems about the captions, plz see my update.

Comment: @WTH Please see edited answer above. Do you have any idea why I need to reset `subcaption`'s default settings for `subtable` here?

Comment: What is weird is that I don't need to reset them for them to be applied to explicit `subtable`s, but only these. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong: there's something I don't get about how this works and how it is meant to work.

Comment: thanks the solution works fine.  I looked at caption.sty and I think you are not using the right options, you should use `\caption@setoptions{sub}` instead of `\caption@setoptions{threepartsubtable}`. That's why later on you have to explicitly reset it to default options. See my update.

Comment: @WTH If you do that, is it possible to add options for `threepartsubtable` in the way that you can add options for `threeparttable`? Anyway, please see amended version which is a bit simpler.